# Cannot link two tables; mysql; entity framework c#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have 3 tables : "userDetails", "address" and "country". "UserDetails" and "address" have 1 to 0..1 relationship, "country" and "address" have 1 to many relationship, "country" table is already filled and "userDetails" has 1 random record.

Now, when I want to add a random record into address, i need to have a link on the "userDetails" and "country". I send link on userDetails record as parameter to my createAddress method, so i can take his id, and EF automaticly adds that record to virtual foreign key field.

But how can i get random record from "country"? I can get random id, but EF doesnt add country recoed with that id. As you can see on screenshot userDetails field is filled and country fied is null.

> ```
>     private address createAddress(userdetails userDetails)
>     {
>         address newAddress = new address();
>         newAddress.addressLine = getRandomString(20);
>         newAddress.city = getRandomString(10);
>         newAddress.postalCode = getRandomInt(6);
>         newAddress.idaddress = userDetails.iduserDetails;
>         newAddress.countryId = randomizer.Next(1,196);
>         //newAddress.country = (country)(from a in db.country where a.idcountry == newAddress.countryId select a);
>         db.address.Add(newAddress);
>         db.SaveChanges();
>         return newAddress;
>     }
> ```
>
> [image]

And here is model of these tables, if it can help you understand my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if record is saved in database? newAdress is just an object and I don't think you should expect that it updates field country when you set field countryId.

Comment: Can you show how did you map database object to class address?

Comment: Entity Framework is example of ORM framework. I mean something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx. I have experience with NHibernate, so I assumed mapping was natural step. I will have to learn more about Entity Framework to understand why do you have this problem.

Comment: I've already solved this problem. I used 
country newCountry = db.country.Find(randomizer.Next(1,196));
And when i use newAddress.countryId=newCountry.idCountry, country field updates automaticly.